# What file change is meteor waiting for?

Tags: meteor, npm

When I run meteor, sometimes I get an error and it hangs on

> => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

I think I've let it sit before and it eventually got past that message, but it always takes a long time. What file change is it waiting for? Is it npm or meteor? And is it slow for others, or is it my Koding box being finicky? Can I just stop the process or should I wait?

I don't need help resolving the error that caused this message in this specific instance, just wondering how to handle meteor errors in general when it hangs on this message and curious as to what it means.

Comment: there should be an error message above that  telling you the location of your error (incl. the file name of the file whose change it is waiting on).

Comment: In this case, the root error was a permission error, and I've already resolved this in another terminal. It's still hanging on that line, so it's not likely waiting for me to resolve the permission error. The `=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.` line shows up even if it isn't a permission error, meaning it's probably waiting for a file related to how the command itself runs.